# Magento cron tab problem

Tags: module, magento-1

I have the following in config.xml in order to set up a cronjob with magento

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <mycompany_mymodule>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>mymodule/observer::editEntries</model>
            </run>
        </mycompany_mymodule>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

my controller is:

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer{
    public function editEntries() {
        /****************/
    }
}
```

and i am getting the following error:

```
'exception ''Mage_Core_Exception'' with message ''Invalid callback: mymodule/observer::editEntries does not exist'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cron\Model\Observer.php(301): Mage::throwException(''Invalid callbac...'')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Cron\Model\Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), ''dispatch'', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent(''default'', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\cron.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent(''default'')
#6 {main}'
```

full config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <mycompany_mymodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </mycompany_mymodule>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <Mymodule>
                <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
            </Mymodule>
        </models>
    </global>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>mymodule/model_cron::editEntries</model>
                </run>
            </mycompany_mymodule>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

----- ediit -----

so the cron attribute should look like this?

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <mycompany_mymodule>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>mycompany_mymodule_model/observer::editEntries</model>
            </run>
        </mycompany_mymodule>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missing model and you need to define models
Just add models to **config.xml**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <mymodule>
            <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
        </mymodule>
    </models>
</global>
```

And Observer.php localation is **app/code/yourmodulecodepool/Mycompany/Mymodule/Model**

**Edit:**

**Issue1:**

as you have set **mymodule/observer** .That mean **mymodule/observer**

mymodule is a model class prefix which  in config.xml

your code  is model prefix  and always be in lower letter

```
<global>
        <models>
            <mymodule> <!--  change <Mymodule> to <mymodule>  -->
                 <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mymodule> <!-- same chnage here -->
        </models>
    </global>
```

**Issue2:**

**mymodule/model_cron** is `run as model` which in run on cron job

magento is manupulate this  it class
by

`mymodule`= `Mycompany_Mymodule_Model`  as i define at config xml

`model_cron` =`Model_Cron`

the final  class  is  `Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Model_Cron` it path should be

```
app/code/yourmodulecodepool/Mycompany/Mymodule/Model/Model/Cron.php
```

If you use `mymodule/model_cron::editEntries` in cron  then  this file path location

```
 app/code/yourmodulecodepool/Mycompany/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php
```

and
class is

```
 Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer
```

**Modified  config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule> <!-- module should be same sa filepath -->
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>

   <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule> <!--  change <Mymodule> to <mymodule>  -->
                 <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mymodule> <!-- same chnage here -->
        </models>
    </global>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>mymodule/observer::editEntries</model>
                </run>
            </mycompany_mymodule>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "Observer is model class an it is not observer" ? thanks for helping

Comment: Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer is model class which is used as observer.It location should in modelfolder

Comment: i have set my model but i am using this tag <class><Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>. isn't correct that way ?

Comment: please full config.xml.thus i can check

Comment: so how the crontab attribute should look like in config.xml ?
is there any way to check where magento is expecting to find the model used for the cronjob ?

Comment: app/code/yourmodulecodepool/Mycompany/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php used as observer

Comment: i think that i understand where the problem is. I will try it and i will come back to confirm that i solved that. thanks again